# How to "italicize after underscoring"

Tags: italic, emphasis

I want to use `\underline` for tensors (please don't question) but, for example, I don't like how `$\underline{K}$` looks. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $$\underline{K}~\underline{\mathrm{K}}$$
\end{document}
```

Very simply, I would expect that the "base" of the character be underlined, not the whole character. That is, get rid of the red part of the underlining. In other words, I would like to underline first and then italicize, instead of italicizing first and then underlining. Can this be achieved? `\mathit{\underline{\mathrm{K}}}` did not work, of course.

**Edit:** Since I want to stay in math mode, here's another detail: let's make it work for `$\mathit{\Pi}$`.

[image: K and K]

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$`. `\underline` uses the full with of the character box which is wider for italics than for upright shape

Comment: Underlining and italicising are different kinds of animal. When you use italic, you use characters from a different font. It isn't a question of the upright character being transformed. It is a different character from a different font. When you underline, that is an addition to what is there, based on the size of the character. TeX doesn't know anything about the 'base' of the character. All it knows is how big the box is. In the case of an italic K, the box is wider than in the case of an upright one.  `soul` works for text, taking account of italic correction, I assume, but not `\ul{$K$}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I usually don't use `$$`, but thanks! @cfr: Thanks! I like how you spend five lines on explaining why it cannot work, just to present a solution in the last line :) [which does not work in math mode, but does in text mode].

Comment: [Possible solution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143041/89497)

Comment: Yes, compare `\underline{\textit{K}}~\ul{\textit{K}}`. `soul`'s `\ul` does provide an advantage here in terms of italic correction (even though I don't like the distance of that underlining).

Comment: What I meant was: you can't do it by underlining and then italicising *per* your suggestion because the characters for italic are not ever upright to be underlined. I don't know how `soul` works but either it approximates using the non-italic font or it somehow else corrects for the italic. What it definitely is not doing is underline the text and then make that text italic.

Comment: I EDITED my answer to work with `\mathit{\Pi}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I stack an underline of a phantom mathrm `K` atop the math K, keeping the stack left aligned.  I compare with the original.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackon[0pt]{$K$}{$\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{K}}}$}
\quad\underline{K}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To turn it into a macro, `\baseunderline{}` that works in different math styles... EDITED to work with `\mathit{\Pi}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\def\baseunderline#1{\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{l}%
  \ThisStyle{\stackon[0pt]{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\let\mathit\relax%
  $\SavedStyle\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#1}}}$}}}
\begin{document}
\[\baseunderline{K}\quad\underline{K}\]
\[\scriptstyle\baseunderline{K}\quad\underline{K}\]
\[\scriptscriptstyle\baseunderline{K}\quad\underline{K}\]
\[  \baseunderline{\mathit{\Pi}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bers points out that for certain applications, defining the stacktype and alignment should be done *inside* the `\ThisStyle` invocation.  To that end, one may actually specify all stacking parameters at the time of invocation, with the following definition:

```
\def\baseunderline#1{%
  \ThisStyle{\stackengine{0pt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\let\mathit\relax%
  $\SavedStyle\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#1}}}$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}
```

Comment: Looks very nice!

Comment: In some applications (e.g., with `\bm`), I found out it may be helpful to have   `\def\stacktype{L} \def\stackalignment{l}` within the body of `\ThisStyle`.

Comment: @bers Perhaps one should just cut to the chase and define it this way: `\def\baseunderline#1{%
  \ThisStyle{\stackengine{0pt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\let\mathit\relax%
  $\SavedStyle\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#1}}}$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}`, which specifies the parameters directly in the invocation.  I'll note it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Combining `\underbar` with `\itshape` in math mode seems to do the trick. Not sure how robust this is though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytensor}[1]{\underbar{\itshape #1}}
\begin{document}
$K$
$\underbar{K}$
$\mytensor{K}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Playing around I bit, I have found `$\underline{\textit{K}}$` which also works. Now, which one is better? Both seem to leave math mode (`\textit`, obviously; `\underbar`, judging from `$\underbar{\mathit{K}}$` failing...

Comment: @bers Since you're using this notation for a tensor, presumably in math mode, I thought using text-mode commands should be avoided.

Comment: I agree. `\underbar` sets its contents in text mode, though: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163280/underbar-changing-the-style-of-font-but-bar-not-why

Comment: That explains why `\underbar{K}` didn't work as I had expected. Perhaps adding `\ensuremath` would help (see edit).

Comment: `$\mytensor{K}$`'s underscore is too long; `\Gamma` is not italic. I am not so positive `\underbar` is the way to go.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the underbar got longer when I added `\ensuremath`. `\Gamma` was just in there to make sure it worked with a math argument.